# What's the most elegant way to deal with nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, and a query that looks like this::

```
select * from table_1
where x.column_1 in (
    select column_2 from table_2
    where column_3 = 'foo')
```

which almost works for me; there are nulls in `column_1` and `column_2` that I want to be considered as matches.

I could write a `union`with this:

```
-- query above
union all
select * from table_1
where column_2 is null
and exists (select * from table_2
    where column_3 = 'foo'
    and column_2 is null)
```

But the would scan each table twice, which seems inefficient.

Is there a way to combine the two queries to make a mire efficient query?

Comment: Which RDBMS, any or a specific instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table_1
where coalesce (column_1,'special value') in 
      (
        select coalesce (column_2,'special value') 
          from table_2
         where column_3 = 'foo'
      )
```

Of course `'special value'` should not be contained in `column_3` of `table_2` and must be compatible to the datatype of the column.

Comment: And what if there is no `'special value'` that can't appear in the data?

Comment: Damn, I knew that someone would pinpoint on that one. Think. First, I narrowed my idea in the last sentence. Second: How often do you have nullable columns which may (and do) contain all possible values?

However, I added the full solution.

Answer (score 2):

Would this not work for you?

```
select  *   
from    table_1 t1
where   EXISTS (
                    select  1
                    from    table_2 t2
                    where   t2.column_3 = 'foo'
                    AND     (
                                    t1.column_1 = t2.column_2
                                OR  (t1.column_1 IS NULL AND t2.column_2 IS NULL)
                            )
                )
```

This would include where they are equal or both NULL.

The reason I avoid `ISNULL, IFNULL, COALESCE` is as @alzaimar stated, the *datatype and special value* issues

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @ypercube this could be simplified for MySQL as

```
select  *   
from    table_1 t1
where   EXISTS (
                    select  1
                    from    table_2 t2
                    where   t2.column_3 = 'foo'
                    AND     t1.column_1 <=> t2.column_2                
                 )
```

Comment: that's a correlated subquery, which would be very inefficient

Comment: But it's 100% correct. My attempt does a full scan (I suppose) and it can't really get more ineffective than that.

Comment: You could simplify the condition using the [(mysql) `<=>` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) to: `AND t1.column_1 <=> t2.column_2`

Comment: @Bohemian this query would be more efficient than the one you accepted.

Comment: @ypercube are you sure? doesn't execute the inner query once for every row in table1? are you saying the optimizer converts it to a join?

Comment: If there are indexes on `table1(column_1)` and on `table2 (column_3, column_2)`, they will be used for the semi-join, yes.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 5.3 have further improvements on the optimizer and how it handles subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select T.* from table_1 T

LEFT JOIN table_2 S ON T.column_1 = S.column_2 OR NULLIF(T.column_1,NULL) = NULLIF(S.column_2 ,NULL)

where column_3 = 'foo'
```

Comment: But nulls won't match using `=`

Comment: @Bohemian Try `<=>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_1 t1 
       INNER JOIN table_2 t2 
               ON t1.column_1 = t2.column_2 
WHERE  t2.column_3 = 'foo' 
       AND t1.column_2 IS NULL 
       AND t2.column_2 IS NULL
```

Comment: (Typo: 2nd last line should have column_1.) That won't work: 1. The JOIN ON will not include rows with t1.column_1 or t1.column_2 null, then the WHERE will only filter that result, losing null matches. 2. The AND of IS NULLs must be ORed (not ANDed) in. (Per 1, into the ON.) 3. This returns * from both tables not just table_1.